# how to make importing data faster in Teradata

Tags: import, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

[image]Recently I use SQL assistant to import CSV file into Teradata.
different timeslot result in different performance, 10 times. Does Teradata has resource management which is similar with SQL Server' Resource Governor or Oracle's resource manager.
And before I import data into a table, need I disable the index on this table firstly? other databases can get good performance via disable the index. Thanks!

need I use fastload tool to replace the method I used above? Thanks!

Comment: Did you increase *Maximum Batch size for simple Imports* in Option-Import to 999? Importing a larger number of rows is *much* faster in Teradata Studio. And for real large numbers go for TPT.

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks for your suggestion! I have increased Max Batch size to 999, which bring slight performance benefit. As for Teradata Studio and TPT, in my company, new software installation is restricted because of license and security.

Comment: If you got access to FastLoad it will also improve performance (the same protocol is used by Studio/TPT). How many rows do you load? Did you check the Primary Index of the target table? Can you show the DDL?

Comment: @denoth, thanks for your quick reply! the number of records is 683,000. the total time spent is 6 hours via import of SQL assistant. please see the attachment for the SQL statement of creating this table. Thanks!

Comment: The table DDL looks ok, doesn't seem to be a bad PI and it's MULTISET, too. 30 rows/second using a large batch size is really slow, a FastLoad should to that in less than a minute. Teradata has a sophisticated workload management. Contact your DBA, maybe your user/query is put in a workload with a delay queue (but usually simple inserts should not be queued)